# HTML input type=file, get the image before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file-io

I'm building a basic social network and in the registration the user uploads a display image.
Basically I wanted to display the image, like a preview on the same page as the form, just after they select it and before the form is submitted.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)

Answer (score 77):

Here is the complete example for previewing image before it gets upload.

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://goo.gl/r57ze"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript  :

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah')
        .attr('src', e.target.result)
        .width(150)
        .height(200);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: it'll not render the urls but it shows the images directly from local storage using embedding image in text... just try this code then commnet

Comment: you misunderstand. the question was why did you use a url shortener(goo.gl)? it hides/obfuscate the urls

Comment: O really sorry..!! Thanks for correction.. I replaced it with original URLs.

Answer (score 68):

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

Answer (score 17):

this can be done very easily with HTML 5, see this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 6):

```js
const inputImg = document.getElementById('imgInput')
const img = document.getElementById('img')

function getImg(event){

     const file = event.target.files[0]; // 0 = get the first file

     // console.log(file);

     let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

     // console.log(url)

     img.src = url
}

inputImg?.addEventListener('change', getImg)
```

```html
<img id='img' alt="images">
<input id="imgInput" accept="image/*" type="file">
```

Answer (score 5):

I feel we had a related discussion earlier: [How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)

Comment: Ah, good spot. I’ve marked the question as a potential duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL.createObjectURL(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
```

This code works for me.