# rendering image for preview from selected file in file input tag

Tags: html, image

Now I have a form field:

```
<input id="my_img_field" type="file"/>
```

After I select the image in the browser, I want to render the selected image file on the target `img` tag:

```
<img id="image_preview" />
```

But I want to do this after the `$('#my_img_field').change` event, i.e. I may want this done when I click some button later.

I heard that this could be done using HTML5 technique. Can someone teach me how?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14053147/2611927

Comment: @Hardy thank you, but I found a minimal approach myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach will work:

```
var file = $('#my_img_field')[0].files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var img = $('#image_preview');
    img.attr('src', this.result);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

the code in vanilla js

```
var file = document.getElementById('my_img_field').files[0]
    var fr = new FileReader()
    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
    fr.onload = function(e) {
      var img = document.getElementById('image_preview')
      img.src = this.result
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be like this

```
const file = document.getElementById('my_img_field').files[0]
const link = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
```