# How to access an image without uploading and display it in an IMG tag

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to read the URL of an image selected in an `<input type="file">`tag and then display the corresponding image without uploading the file to the server first.

`<input type='flie'id='anything' name='anything'>`

and outputted in

`<div id='showimg'></div>`

without uploading it first.

Comment: try googling for upload file using ajax

Comment: @JoSSte you may as well recommend Stack Overflow internal search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=upload+ajax

Comment: its not helpful.. i just want img in that div when i choose some pic from input type file.. by using onchange function..

Comment: "Upload" infers transferring an image from the client to the server. If you just want to display the image, that is ENTIRELY different.

Comment: @JoSSte instead of writing comment, **flag** question as duplicate - this results in comment like mine above.

Comment: i have already flagged it not enough info, so I couldn't add another flag...

Comment: @barbsan thnx for solution...

Comment: @JoSSte.. Yeah right.. now I got ur point.. thnx..

Answer (score 1):

**"Upload"** infers transferring an image from the client to the server. If you just want to display the image, that is ENTIRELY different. 
what you want is to have your `<input type=image>`, and have an `onchange` action which reads the path of the image, and then takes that path and puts in the src part of an `img` tag.

Something like this: (no guarantee for this to work. look up the specifics...)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateimgref(){
  var img = document.getElementById("outputimg");
  var input = document.getElementById("imginput");
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    img.href = input.result;
  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="image" id="imginput" onchange="updateimgref()">
<img id="outputimg" href="myblankplaceholder.png">
</body>
</html>
```

se also 
[HTML input type=file, get the image before submitting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802580/html-input-type-file-get-the-image-before-submitting-the-form)

Comment: Tysm man...(y)..

Comment: if it helped, mark it as accepted answer ;-)