# How do I use input tag result to img.src

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to use input result as image source how can I do that?

I try to use input id as `img.src` but that clearly does not work, I also try to use `img` tag and use the put input result as `img` tag `src`, then call it on `canvas`, but also did not work, I'm really newbie on coding, so please my apologize if my question seems stupid:

html

```
<canvas id="image"></canvas>
```

js

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
canvas.width = img.naturalWidth
canvas.height = img.naturalHeight
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a certain action, just take the input value and put it in the image src attribute..i guess should work? I have used a button as action here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="image_src" id="image-src">
    <img id="input-image">
    <button onClick="putInputValue()">Use</button>
    <script>
        function putInputValue() {
            var imageSrcValue = document.getElementById("image-src").value;
            var image = document.getElementById("input-image");
            image.setAttribute('src', imageSrcValue);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your comment on this answer requires a totally new implementation than the one you asked in your question.

If you want to just render the input url and show it as an image, you should go with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14053147/6935763

Comment: sorry long respones, i want something like when i upload image using input type, the file will automatically displayed, not with action button

Comment: Updated my answer, you should know that your initial question is totally different than what you said here.

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm not that good at english and wording, but thx for your help very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to draw into a `canvas` if that's the requirement is the that - just for the example, I'm using a `stackoverflow` logo below once you do not provide a value for the input field:

```js
(function () {
  // picking up the elements from the DOM
  const input = document.getElementById('imageSrc');
  const button = document.getElementById('drawButton');
  
  // attaching click event to button
  button.onclick = draw;

  // define drawing
  function draw() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('image');
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // clearing canvas not to show the previous drawing
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // setting up the image source
    let imgSrc = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a';

    if (input.value !== '') {
      imgSrc = input.value;
    }

    // handling drawing into the canvas
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = imgSrc;
  }      
})();
```

```css
#image {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>    
  <input id="imageSrc" type="text" />
  <button id="drawButton">Draw</div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Canvas:</p>
  <canvas id="image" />
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry for long response, i want something like when you upload file using input tag, the image will automatically upload to canvas without action button

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? There is an `onkeypress` event for `input` tags, you might want to use that for catching events like that. So basically instead of using `onclick` event there is a different one to listen. Let me know you need help to change the code.

Comment: If the answer was helpful and solved your problem, please consider marking as the answer. Thank you!