# get image height and width in file tag javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)
>   [How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)
>   [get image height and width in file tag using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633197/get-image-height-and-width-in-file-tag-using-javascript)

how can i get the height and width of image without page refresh in file tag?

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE></TITLE>

<script language="javascript">

function getW()

{

var theImg = document.getElementById('testimg');

alert(theImg.width);

}

function getH()

{

var theImg = document.getElementById('testimg');

alert(theImg.height);

}

</script>

</HEAD>



<BODY>


<input type="file" id="testimg"/>

<input type="button" value="get Width" onclick="getW()"/>

<input type="button" value="get Height" onclick="getH()"/>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

i get the image height and width of image using php code, but that time page will be refreshed, without page refresh i get image size but not a height and width....

Comment: Same question?? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633190/get-image-height-and-width-in-file-tag-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript cannot access the file system of the browser's computer. It has no way to read the width and height of that file.

Comment: I thought it could with HTML5. I remember seeing thing such as a MP3 player with JS + HTML

Answer (score 0):

Please read this

[Should setting an image src to data URL be available immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776670/should-setting-an-image-src-to-dataurl-be-available-immediately)

[How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)