# get image height and width in file tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [get image height and width in file tag javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633190/get-image-height-and-width-in-file-tag-javascript)
>   [Determining image file size + dimensions via Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript)
>   [How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)

how can i get the height and width of image without page refresh in file tag?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE></TITLE>
    <script language="javascript">
    function getW()
    {
        var theImg = document.getElementById('testimg');
        alert(theImg.width);
    }

    function getH()
    {
        var theImg = document.getElementById('testimg');
        alert(theImg.height);
    }
    </script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>        
<input type="file" id="testimg"/>
    <input type="button" value="get Width" onclick="getW()"/>
    <input type="button" value="get Height" onclick="getH()"/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

i get the image height and width of image using php code, but that time page will be refreshed, without page refresh i get image size but not a height and width....

Comment: lolwut? 2 questions like this one after another? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633190/get-image-height-and-width-in-file-tag-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310378/determining-image-file-size-dimensions-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onload` event:

```
document.getElementById('testimg').onload = function() {
  alert(document.getElementById('testimg').offsetHeight);
}
```

You can change the action in the function, for example, making your buttons visible, or un-disabled, up to you.

Not sure I understand your question, but Javascript will need to load the image before you can get its dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to do in a cross-browser way.

The only cross-browser way that comes to my mind (but is not simple) is to upload the file ajax style, render that image (could be hidden) and get its size with `img.width` and `img.height`.

Hope this helps. Cheers