# Rails image preview across all browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, file-upload, cross-browser, image-uploading

Is it possible to preview image (on upload) before saving across all the browsers.
I have implemented this way for Firefox:

```
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src = what.files[0].getAsDataURL();
```

this works fine, and, for IE

```
document.getElementById("preview-photo").src = what.value;
```

this docent work and same case with other browsers like Chrome and Safari.
Currently I can see preview only in Firefox, other browsers not showing preview.

Please, advise me how to work on this.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with ruby-on-rails? This doesn't seem at all specific to Rails

Answer (score 0):

There's no completely cross-browser way to do this due to security settings in most browsers preventing file control access.

This may indicate a work-around for FF3, IE7, and a handful of other cases:

[How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)