# Show the image preview before uploading it to the server

Tags: jquery, image, upload

Hello I am looking for a Javascript or jQuery based solution to show an image preview of the SELECTED image and not of the uploaded one.
So as soon as the user selects the image a preview will be shown of this image.
I do not have any code, I am pretty lost here.
I need a solution HTML + Javascript or jQuery based.
I can also use some PHP if necessary

Comment: [How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript)

This should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you need to use the [HTML5 File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/). Almost every latest browsers support this feature except IE9. Safari 5.1 supports this but it's still in beta. You can check the HTML5 File API browser compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=file+api).

There are good tutorials about using the HTML5 File API to display preview like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3a.c2.a0Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) or [this](http://robertnyman.com/2010/12/16/utilizing-the-html5-file-api-to-choose-upload-preview-and-see-progress-for-multiple-files/).

If you need more, you can find more with [googling](http://www.google.co.kr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=file+api+image+preview). You may need to use [Progressive enhacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).